# Encoding Dilema ! %C3%A9 vs e%CC%81

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

if you look to the two links bellow they look the same, but one of them works and the other is not working, after analysing the problem it seems that ther's a diffrence in interpretation of the "é" character and all the accentuated characters and the encoder either treat it as on char or the letter without accentuation + the accetnuation char

This problem is causing the images on website to be broken but they are here in the FTP

The question is how to fix that, is the fix in wordpress, database or server ?

Thank's and sorry for my poor english.

[http://r20med.regions20.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Portes-Ouvertes-sur-le-tri-sélectif-à-Hai-Essabah-Oran_017.jpg](http://r20med.regions20.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Portes-Ouvertes-sur-le-tri-se%CC%81lectif-a%CC%80-Hai-Essabah-Oran_017.jpg)

[http://r20med.regions20.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Portes-Ouvertes-sur-le-tri-sélectif-à-Hai-Essabah-Oran_017.jpg](http://r20med.regions20.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Portes-Ouvertes-sur-le-tri-s%C3%A9lectif-%C3%A0-Hai-Essabah-Oran_017.jpg)

Comment: this  is encoding issue, upload utf-8 filename

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the screen capture below (taken from a text editor after copy-pasting your links above), you can see the difference.

[image: difference in accents]

The easiest solution I found was to change the filenames in an editor that only uses the accentuation you can see in the first row.

**Conclusion:** never trust uploads! Always check them for everything that's around! :) (This is true for filenames, texts, HTML, etc. - even if they are not intended to be harmful, they may block functions of your website / app and cause other problems!)

**Note:**

- not all text editors show them to be different, so choose one that does!
- if it is possible, get rid of accents in filenames (if uploaded use a function to sanitise them, or even make them like a slug in Wordpress with [sanitize_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) or [sanitize_title_with_dashes()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes))

Comment: Yes that what i did to spot the difference, now i am searching for a way to bulk rename all the images since ther's a lot of images